# why so many constructors are called when I clone a DataTable?

Tags: c#, constructor, datatable

Please, help!
I have some inherited classes, shown here:

```
public class DataTableA : DataTable
{
    // ...
    public DataTable CloneMe()
    {
        DataTable table = this;
        return table.Clone();
    }
}

public class DataTableB : DataTableA
{
    // ...
}

public class DataTableC : DataTableB
{
    // ...

    public void Test()
    {
        DataTable table = this.CloneMe(); 
    }
}
```

When I call method Test (class DataTableC) the following constructors are consequentially called:

1. Constructor of DataTable
2. Constructor of DataTableA
3. Constructor of DataTableB
4. Constructor of DataTableC

But why? I expected calling of "Constructor of DataTable" only.

Comment: Because that's how inheritance works? The first thing that happens when you call the constructor of a derived class is that it calls the constructor of its parent class.

Comment: @john unless you write a specific constructor for the derived class without the ```:base()```

Comment: @goaty If you don't specifically call base(), it is implicitly called.

Comment: @john right, my bad

Comment: no, John, I did not call the constructor of a derived class, in fact I only called "Clone()" method of highest "DataTable" class.

Comment: C#  calls it. You don't have to manually, unless your only base class constructor takes an argument, in which case you need to manually call base in order to specify the parameters.

Comment: @poke, Thank you !!!

Comment: @GordonFreeman You should consider *upvoting* helpful answers even if they didn’t ultimately resolve the question.

Comment: @poke, certainly, I had upvoted your advice the same hour, but system said that I had no enough reputation to reflect my votes.

Comment: @poke, Lot of thanks one more time, sir !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, when creating an instance of type `X`, and that type has a base class `Y`, then the constructor of `Y` will be called before the constructor of `X`. This idea is continued for any length of inheritance.

So in your case, in order to create an instance of `DataTableC`, the constructor of `DataTableB` needs to be called first. Before calling the constructor of `DataTableB`, the constructor of `DataTableA` needs to be called first, which again requires the constructor of `DataTable` to run.

This is the normal behavior when creating a new instance. But you’re using `DataTable.Clone` here, so where exactly are you creating a new instance of `DataTableC`?

This comes down to the [implementation of `DataTable.Clone`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/DataTable.cs,2144). Internally, it uses the [`DataTable.CreateInstance` method](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/DataTable.cs,38a938c4997d9da7), which itself uses reflection to create a new instance of the current type:

```
protected virtual DataTable CreateInstance() {
    return (DataTable) Activator.CreateInstance(this.GetType(), true);
}
```

In your case, since the current type is `DataTableC`, a new instance of `DataTableC` is being created, which explains why all those constructors are called.

Comment: poke, It seems that only you have catched truth of matter

Comment: It's so strange behavior of DataTable.Clone method,  How can I call "Clone" to obtain a DataTable (not DataTableC, but column structure must be from DataTableC) ?

Comment: Actually, it’s a pretty smart implementation. Why do you need an explicit `DataTable`? A `DataTableC` is also a `DataTable`. So just use the cloned object as a `DataTable`.

Comment: No,no, I  need an explicit exactly DataTable, because DataTableC contains many other objects, which I have not to create.

Comment: Then you will need to implement the clone logic yourself. `DataTable.Clone` cannot do this.

Comment: I want to copy a column structure of DataTableC to new DataTable object, without creaing DataTableC and its associated objects.

Answer (score 0):

```
public DataTable CloneMe()
{
  return new DataView(this, "0=1", null, DataViewRowState.CurrentRows).ToTable();
}
```

This method clones DataTable (or any object of derived class) without creating DataTableC (DataTableA, DataTableB) object. Explicit DataTable object only.